# Route packets from one interface to another interface alias

Tags: iptables, routing

There are internal interface eth4 (192.168.4.0/24) and external eth0 (ex. 1.1.1.1) with eth0:4 (ex. 4.4.4.4) alias. How to masquerade and forward traffic to eth0:4 from eth4? What I need is that all traffic that comes from eth4 on internet would be seen as from 4.4.4.4 destination other traffic should go to eth0 (there are more internat interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

```
# iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.4.0/24 !-d 192.168.0.0/16 -j SNAT --to-source 4.4.4.4
```